# Sticky button inside an iframe which relies on page scrolling

Tags: html, css

How do i make a sticky button inside an iframe? I mean, when you use position:sticky or -web-sticky, the button does not seem to detect it when the
page is being scrolled.

how do I make this?

Comment: can you please upload some code then i can get some more idea

Answer (score -1, accepted):

when I want sticky code use inside in iframe then i am always use **Sticky-Kit** use this one i'd given link [click here](http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/)

It is just simple

Just call stick_in_parent on the elements you want to be stuck inside of their parent. Sticky elements “bottom out” so they never leave the container, no more worrying if a sticky element will accidentally cover your footer.

If manual way

```
<style>
div.sticky {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background-color: yellow;
    padding: 50px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
</style>

<div class="sticky">I will stick</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, i think i might use that as last option, is there another way doing it without using 3rd party css?

Comment: check this one i have either or try this one https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_sticky_element

Comment: yeah i tried that, it works on elements outside the iframe, however it does not on elements inside the frame

Comment: are you sure sticky-kit library works for items inside an iframe? there's not a single line of code managing this

Comment: @maurice - any chance you made this work, if so, could you please share how you have resolved?